# Posting multipart form to external URL php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

In my page, I have a form to upload photos on an external service which provides an api, upload.im, and I need to get back the URL where the image was uploaded. I really can't get this to work...

The documentation page for this api is [here](http://uploads.im/apidocs).

I added a form to my PHP page:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="UploadForm" id="UploadForm" action="http://uploads.im/api" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
    <input type="file" name="upload" id="upload" />
    <input type="hidden" name="resize_width" id="resize_width" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="thumb_width" id="thumb_width" value="250" />
    <input type="hidden" name="format" id="format" value="xml" />
    <input type="submit" id="Submit" name="Submit" />
</form>
```

I also tried to use this jQuery code to submit the form with the selected image:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#UploadForm').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = new FormData(jQuery('UploadForm')[0]);
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'http://uploads.im/api',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

With this code, I get the error in the console: 
[image: screen.png]

Which is the error code from the API; this means the code works, but something in the way the form is submitted is wrong. Where is the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: The form is fine, the problem is in the js code, I'm trying to fix it.

Comment: Shouldn't `e.preventDefault();` be at the end?

Comment: Also why are you using `jQuery('UploadForm')[0]` as opposed to `$(this)[0]`, and `jQuery.ajax` as opposed to `$.ajax`?

Comment: Check my answer with refer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, I just made a few changes in the JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#UploadForm').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = new FormData($(this));
        data.append('upload', $('#upload')[0].files[0]);

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'http://uploads.im/api',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                console.log(data.data.thumb_url);
                console.log(data.data.img_url);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Form's name is `UploadForm`. Is it right to write `var data = new FormData($('#upload'));`. I think it should be `UploadForm` instead of `upload`...

Comment: You could even use $(this) instead of $('#UploadForm'), but still not working in firefox.

Comment: I've updated your answer, adding the code that worked in both Firefox and Chrome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be to do with this line:

```
var data = new FormData(jQuery('UploadForm')[0]);
```

It should be `#UploadForm`.

Comment: Your code seems to work. I get an `XMLDocument` in the JS console. How can I read this?

Comment: @PWhite try double-clicking the XMLDocument.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below.

```
var data = new FormData( $('#UploadForm') );
```

Pass the Node to FormData Constructor:
The FormData() constructor creates a new FormData object

Parameter: An HTML `<form>` element — when specified, the FormData object will be populated with the form's current keys/values. It will also encode file input content.

Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData

Comment: I get an error in JS console with this code: `TypeError: Argument 1 of FormData.constructor does not implement interface HTMLFormElement.`